# How to show a JS modal window during Rails rake task before redirection happen?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

I've this inside my **orders.html.erb**

`<%= link_to  "Create Next Week Orders", create_next_week_orders_path, class: "btn btn-primary" %>`

That points to this method inside **static_pages_controller.rb**

```
def create_next_week_orders
    %x(bundle exec rake create_orders_next_week)
    redirect_to root_path
end
```

What happened here is, when user click the button, the rake task will be running and it takes some seconds to finish before the `redirect_to` is triggered.

What I actually want is:

1. User click the button
2. A JS [modal window](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) shows up and at the same time, trigger the rake task
3. Rake task running till finish (modal window still open)
4. Rake task finish → `redirect_to` is triggered

How do I achieve this flow?

Is it possible to make it like this?

```
def create_next_week_orders
    respond_to :js
    %x(bundle exec rake create_orders_next_week)
    respond_to :html
end
```

My **routes.rb**

```
get "create_next_week_orders"     => "static_pages#create_next_week_orders"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this:

1. You need to add click event handler to your button that will open the modal

   $(function(){
     $(".your-button").click(function(){
       /* code to show modal */
     })
   })
2. And set remote option as true in your button

   in your view: <%= link_to "Your Button", path_to_action, class: ".your-button", remote: true %>
3. Then in the controller action:

   def create_next_week_orders
       %x(bundle exec rake create_orders_next_week)
       render :js => "window.location('#{root_path}')"
   end